While building the Azure pipeline getting an error like .NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), usedotnetcli/restore
While building the azure pipelines with classic editor i am getting the below error in build
.NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
I didn't try. Can someone tell how to resolve this issue

The error message provides you with 3 options to resolve (mitigate) the issue. When you wrote "I didn't try", what didn't you try?

Hi divya bommerla, can you try the solutions in the error message? If they don't work, you can share more details such as your pipeline configuration and the debug logs for troubleshooting the issue.

The error message has provided the solutions to the error.
Here is the detailed steps:

Use dotnet cli to restore:
Add the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to restore the solution before your build task


Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore
Add the NuGet tool installer task with version 5.8 before the NuGet restore task and the build task.


Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
In your project directory, create a global.json file (if it doesn’t exist). Specify the desired SDK version in the version field. For example:
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.100"
  }
}



